# In Postgres, running ANALYZE changes behaviour of ILIKE clause with COLLATE

Tags: postgresql

We are migrating an application from SQL Server to Postgres and attempting to emulate various aspects of the case insensitivity of SQL Server. We have created a non-deterministic collation to support case-insensitive matching of foreign keys and equality comparisons.

But we are seeing some weird behaviour when using ILIKE which we can't explain, and would appreciate some assistance.

To see the behaviour, run the following on a fresh database:

```
CREATE COLLATION IF NOT EXISTS public.ci (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sort_test;

CREATE TABLE sort_test (a text COLLATE public.ci);

INSERT INTO sort_test SELECT md5(n::text) FROM generate_series(1, 10000) n;

-- Removing the following line fixes the issue
ANALYZE sort_test;

-- This line throws "nondeterministic collations are not supported for ILIKE"
SELECT * FROM sort_test WHERE a ILIKE 'c4ca4238a0%' COLLATE "und-x-icu";
```

Why does running the ANALYZE statement break the ILIKE statement?

Comment: By the way, we are using text rather than citext because of lack of support for citext in Entity Framework 6

Comment: That's a bug, you should report it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I think this recent bug report here is the same issue: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAAFmbbN6iY-g4Of4k5S7t52Cvcvk_bO%3DSxZOySa6F4pR01eUTw%40mail.gmail.com#3d7e55a5d2b5e067896d3be3e103cbc0

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior [is a PostgreSQL bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAAFmbbN6iY-g4Of4k5S7t52Cvcvk_bO%3DSxZOySa6F4pR01eUTw%40mail.gmail.com#3d7e55a5d2b5e067896d3be3e103cbc0).

The reason why it works without the `ANALYZE` is that the error is thrown when applying the operator to the “histogram bounds” in the statistics. Before `ANALYZE` there are no statistics, so no error is thrown.